# Is it stuck in a counting loop?

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

Given a list of non-negative integers the function \$f\$ replaces every integer with the number of identical integers preceding it (not necessarily contiguously). So

```
f [1,1,2,2,1,3,3] = [1,2,1,2,3,1,2]
```

We will say that a list, \$X\$, is *in a loop* if there is some positive integer \$n\$ such that \$f^n X = X\$.  That is you can apply the function to \$X\$ some number of times to arrive at \$X\$.

Your task is to take a list as input and determine if that list is in a loop. You should output one of two consistent values, one if it is in a loop and the other if it is not.

This is code-golf. The goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

---

A note: There are other ways to formulate this condition.

### Test cases

```
[2,2] -> False
[1,1] -> True
[1,2] -> True
[1,1,2,2,3,3] -> True
[1,2,3,1,4,2,5,3] -> True
[1,2,1,3,1,2] -> True
[1,2,1,3,1,3,4,6] -> False
[1,2,2,3] -> False
```

Comment: @Arnauld I think it is not the length of the run of identical integers, but the total number in the list. So the third element should be `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`. Perhaps an example with the numbers not being grouped would help.

Comment: It looks like the true ones all have a cycle length of 2, and the false ones converge to something with a cycle length of 2 also, just not including the original input.  i don't see how to prove it though -- is it always true?

Comment: @Jonah It is always true. I found it difficult to prove, but there's a stronger claim that's easier to prove, and may also be helpful to golfing.

Comment: I would be curious to see how you approached the proof.

Comment: I think you can reasonably well prove f^3=f, which I think implies @Jonah's statement

Comment: @Jonah I proved that everything stuck in a loop has property P and then that everything with property P is stuck in a loop of size 2.

Comment: @WheatWizard aren't we kind of transposing Young diagrams in the loop?

Comment: @Albert.Lang Yes. :)

Comment: It looks like the condition is that the input has to be a [stackable sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/144201/20260) (1-indexed)? Definitely the result of `f` is stackable, so if the initial list is not, we're never looping back to it. And if it's stackable, the loop length is 2, except for the input `[1]` or `[]` it's 1.

Comment: @xnor That was the condition I had found, so its a duplicate. I had a look for challenges mentioning "Young tableaux" and a couple of related terms but didn't find that one before I posted.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @WheatWizard It's a cool connection! I hadn't known about it.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
-:(1#.]=]\)^:2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/da00DJX1Ym1jYzTjrIz@a3KlJmfkK6iHFJWWZFSqQ3hpCoYKhgimEZKoghEQGisYI8kCuYYKJkDaFFXYECwB1azulphTjDDfCNlQmFJjoClmyMJAo/8DAA)

This uses the fact I conjectured in the comments, which WheatWizard confirmed is true:

> It looks like the true ones all have a cycle length of 2, and the false ones converge to something with a cycle length of 2 also, just not including the original input.

So, we simply apply the transformation twice, and check if the result matches the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ċṪ‘ƊƤ⁺⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I98Odqx41zDjWdWzJo8Zdjxr3/H@4c5/1o4Y5Crp2Co8a5lofbgcKqHA93L3l4Y5ND3csCjvW9ahpzeF2IBH5/3@0kY5RLEipW2JOcSpXtKGOIZgbUlQK5hmh8IB8IDTWMUZVAxQx1DEB0qYYMoZgOSOsosZAPWaoloONRwj9BwA)

A monadic link taking a list of integers and returning 1 if a loop and 0 if not. Uses @Jonah’s observation that we only need to apply the transformation twice and check whether we get back to where we started.

### Previous solution, 9 bytes

```
ċṪ‘ƊƤ⁺ÐL⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I98Odqx41zDjWdWzJo8Zdhyf4PGrc8//hzn3WjxrmKOjaKTxqmGt9uB0ooML1cPeWhzs2PdyxKOxY16OmNYfbgUTk///RRjpGsSClbok5xalc0YY6hmBuSFEpmGeEwgPygdBYxxhVDVDEUMcESJtiyBiC5YywihoD9ZihWg42HiH0HwA)

A monadic link taking a list of integers and returning 1 if a loop and 0 if not.

### Explanation

```
ċṪ‘ƊƤ     | For each prefix, count the number of times the popped tail appears and then increment by 1
     ⁺ÐL  | Repeat this again until a value is seen for the second time, returning the last value that has not been seen before
        ⁼ | Check whether equal to the original argument
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

Naive implementation. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
a=>(g=a=>g[a]?a+""==b:g(g[a]=a.map(p=v=>p[v]=-~p[v])))(b=a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc9BC4IwFAfwe59CPG00lc3qEDy79Qm6iYen6SjMDS2PffU1NUFCww32GPu9P3t3bLHJ6pt@epW65qYAgxARCfaUMSYn3LouQHqUpLsC@g/UREMLkY7bBLx3VyilJAWkJlNVo8rcL5UkBYkFE/bNma4gcM5YNvnmh3LGZ@ilfs1IsVpaa3fIwrFjOdMqzna27gf9R/LeihWZgwxt7uGbuTB8/83pWCM1Hw)

#### Commented

```javascript
a => (                // a[] = input array
  g =                 // g is a recursive function taking ...
  a =>                // ... the current state a[] of the array
  g[a] ?              // if we've encountered a[] before:
    a + "" == b       //   stop and return true if this is the original array
  :                   // else:
    g(                //   do a recursive call:
      g[a] =          //     mark a[] as encountered
      a.map(p =       //     p is on object used to count 'preceding' values
      v =>            //     for each value v in a[]:
        p[v] = -~p[v] //       increment p[v]
      )               //     end of map()
    )                 //   end of recursive call
)(b = a)              // initial call to g with a[] saved in b[]
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

Optimized version using [Jonah's conjecture](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268547/58563).

```javascript
a=>a+""==(g=a=>a.map(p=v=>p[v]=-~p[v]))(g(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RW0nJ1lYj3RbE1stNLNAosC2ztSuILou11a0DUZqaGukaiZqa/5Pz84rzc1L1cvLTNdI0oo10jIByCshAX1/BLTGnOJULTamhjiEWpSFFpVhUGhGtEqgWCI11jGE6cJsJVGWoYwKkTSGq8ag0BKs1IsJMiEpjoLlmUDNxeB7sTGRvwZT@BwA)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

Further optimized, knowing that we're actually looking for a [stackable sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144201/stackable-sequences) as pointed out by [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor). This is basically a 1-indexed version of my answer to the other challenge.

```javascript
a=>a.every(k=>a[a[-k]=-~a[-k--],-k]--|!k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RL7UstahSIxvIjE6M1s2OtdWtA9G6urE6QJ6ubo1itub/5Py84vycVL2c/HSNNI1oIx2jWE1NBWSgr6/glphTnMqFptRQxxCL0pCiUiwqjYhWCVQLhMY6xjAduM0EqjLUMQHSphDVeFQagtUaEWEmRKUx0FwzqJk4PA92JrK3YEr/AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 115 bytes

```py
def f(a):
 q=[a]
 while(l:=[sum(k==j for k in q[-1][:i+1])for i,j in enumerate(q[-1])])not in q:q+=[l]
 return l==a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBT8QgEIXP8ismvRSyrAmta0wTPHr05A17YLPTLLuUUqAaf32lJMZsNBzIe/Pxhhn/lc6Ta598WNcTDjBQzToCs1S6J/B5Nhap7aSKy0ivUl5gmAJcwTiY1V70qjM70bPNNPyy2eiWEYNOSAvAeuamVPhu3kllc2rAtAQHVkq9RpBQVZVqeNPD/hletI1IlOCiyLewFNXcqKzzaXl7y2RH8Id8H/5URKk1/7ptfvN427zE/1r5g4SUGbdBBmMTBvo6OeQQ76O3JtH63dUsb@5OczjmmUbtKX5oy8H8EFtcZjISI4ZUVg1SwpEQH4zLRMKYIvitfqrZ@g0)